# 2D shadow from polar coordinates has hard cut-off at a certain radius

Tags: opengl, 2d, glsl, shadows, shadow-mapping

I'm trying to cast shadows from a 1D texture that goes from white to back according to the distance given by an occlusion map. That part I think I got it right. The problem lies on the algorithm to check if a given pixel is in shadow.

[image: Image of shadow showing hard cutoff]

As you can see, the outer limits are clamped, as if it is in shadow. The result I would expect is that it would slowly fade. I don't know why my shader yields this result.

Here is the shader I use for casting the shadows:

```
#version 330
#define numTextures 32
#define PI 3.14


in vec2 TexCoords;
in vec4 pass_colors;
in vec4 fragPos;
in vec4 worldFragPos;
in mat4 outWorld;

out vec4 color;
uniform vec4 ambientColor;   
uniform sampler2D texture_diffuse;
uniform float radius;
uniform vec2 screenResolution;
uniform int lightCounter;

struct LightData
{ 
    float radius;
    vec3 position;        //light position, normalized
    vec4 color;      //light RGBA -- alpha is intensity
};

uniform LightData lights[numTextures];
uniform sampler2D shadows;


float n3ddistance(vec3 first_point, vec3 second_point)
{
    float x = first_point.x-second_point.x;
    float y = first_point.y-second_point.y;
    float val = x*x + y*y;
    return sqrt(val);
}


float sample(vec2 coord, float r) {
    return step(r, texture(shadows, coord).r);
}

float GetShadow(int lightIndex)
{
    vec2 dir = fragPos.xy - lights[lightIndex].position.xy;
    dir /= lights[lightIndex].radius / 2;
    //rectangular to polar
    dir.y *= -1;
    vec2 norm = dir.st;// * 2.0 - 1.0;
    float theta = atan(norm.y, norm.x);
    float r = length(norm);
    float coord = (theta + PI) / (2.0*PI);

    //the tex coord to sample our 1D lookup texture 
    //always 0.0 on y axis
    vec2 tc = vec2(coord, 0.0);

    return sample(tc, r); 
}


vec3 GetColor(int lightIndex)
{
    float dst = n3ddistance(lights[lightIndex].position.xyz, fragPos.xyz);
    float intensity = clamp(1.0 - dst / lights[lightIndex].radius, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec3 color = lights[lightIndex].color.rgb * intensity * GetShadow(lightIndex);
    return color;
}


void main()
{
    
    vec4 DiffuseColor = vec4(texture(texture_diffuse, TexCoords)) * pass_colors;

    vec3 sum = vec3(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < lightCounter; i++)
        sum += GetColor(i);

    vec3 intensity = ambientColor.xyz + sum;
    vec3 finalColor = DiffuseColor.rgb * intensity;
    color = vec4(finalColor.rgb, DiffuseColor.a);
    if (color.a <= 0.0) 
        discard;
}
```

And here is the shader responsable for writing to that 1D texture

```
#version 330

#define PI 3.14159265359

in vec2 TexCoords;
in vec4 fragPos;
in vec3 lightPos;

out vec4 color;

uniform float radius;
uniform sampler2D occlusion;

void main()
{
    float distance = 1;

    for (float y=0.0; y < radius; y += 1.0)
    {
        vec2 norm = vec2(TexCoords.s, y / radius) * 2.0 - 1.0;
        float theta = PI * 1.5 + norm.x * PI; 
        float r = (1.0 + norm.y) * 0.5;
        vec2 coord = vec2(-r * sin(theta), -r * cos(theta))/2.0 + 0.5;
        
        vec4 data = texture(occlusion, coord);
        float dst = y/radius;
        float caster = data.r;
        if (caster > 0.75) {
            distance = min(distance, dst);
            break;
        }
    } 
  color = vec4(vec3(distance), 1.0);
}
```

How can I get a smooth fall-off instead of this sudden stop at a particular radius?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So It seems I has to use this line

```
 return sample(tc, r)* smoothstep(1.0, 0.0, r);
```

which solves the problem...Thank you!